# Filtering graph data on barChart with disabled brush area

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm new to d3/dc.js realm and I'm bit stuck with one problem. I have a bar chart created using dc.js in React with disabled brush area:

```
chart
  .x(this.scale)
  .xUnits(this.units)
  .gap(0)
  .round(this.round)
  .centerBar(false)
  .brushOn(false)
```

Data in this chart are grouped on x-axis (values are floating numbers from range -160 to 160, and bars are always grouping these numbers by 10. So one bar on x-axis contains all numbers in range from -160 to -150, from -150 to -140 etc.).

On the same page there is table with some filtered data from the table. What I need to do is: Hover over table row with some data and highlight specific bar which contains that data. Eg. I hover over value -137.768 and I need highlight bar for values -140 to - 130. Rest of the bars should be dimmed (grey out). I'm currently using `replaceFilter` to highlight that bar. However for that I need brush area on (which I don't want to) otherwise filter does nothing. Is there any other way how to do this without brush area?

Reason for this is that I don't want the user to be able to select some range from bar chart manually. I only want to highlight bars when user hovers over some table row.

Thanks in advance for any help.